# Love 2D and ffi luajit, trying to use the PHYSFS_enumerateFiles()

Tags: lua, lua-table, luajit

It always return a String which is (at least I guess) the table identifier someone can help in anyway?

Thats my function:

```
function listFiles(dir)
    local ffi = require("ffi")
    ffi.cdef[[char ** PHYSFS_enumerateFiles (   const char *    dir  );]]
    local liblove = ffi.os == "Windows" and ffi.load("love") or ffi.C
    local tb={}
    tb=liblove.PHYSFS_enumerateFiles(dir)
    return tb
end
```

It should return me a String with filecontents of the "Dir" I pass to it, but it doesnt. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Just a note: consider always using parenthesis when you mix *and* and *or* (in any language), to avoid operator precedence related surprises.

Comment: Another thing, what is value of `dir` when you call this function, and what are actual contents of this directory? And if `dir` is relative path, also what is current working directory when you call this function?

Comment: I forget to add the "dir" to the search path. Doing this and converting the char** to char* and then to String, it would work, right?

Comment: I am passing this C:/Users/Josué/Desktop/love/Texture Packs/ It returns nothing. And the contents of this is a folder named default wich  bunch of pngs. And if I try to enumerate it with love filesystem, it returns a table code

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [reference](http://icculus.org/physfs/docs/html/physfs_8h.html#a0f4ae950c2dae0735a91263ddd20fbf4) properly. The enumeration function returns a pointer to string pointers, after the last string follows a NULL pointer. Conversion from `char*` to Lua string can be done with `ffi.string`.